# Dumping BIOS and USB bootloader

Tags: bios

Edward Snowden suggests to have the bootloader on a USB stick to prevent evil maid attacks and to dump the BIOS, hash it and compare it everytime.

1. Is using Tails from a USB stick means the bootloader is on the USB stick or how do I get the bootloader on a USB stick?
2. How do I dump the BIOS, hash it and compare everytime?

Comment: If the adversary controls the BIOS, they could probably make it appear as if nothing has changed. Checking the hash may reveal less complex replacements however.

Comment: Frankly, Snowden doesn't really understand what he's talking about here. It would be easy to fool this. What you want is TPM-based SRTM.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, booting from a USB stick on a system which has BIOS implemented means that the bootloader is on the USB stick. The start of the stick will have a bootable partition (containing a MBR) which the BIOS calls to load the OS.

Here's a question asking [how to dump the BIOS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126132/how-to-dump-bios-data-to-a-file#127607).